# How to Make a Custom Extension for Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, system.reactive

It is not hard to find an example of [how to make a custom LINQ extension method](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37373/Writing-Custom-LINQ-Extension-Methods).  But I can't find an example of how to make a custom Rx extension method.

Can someone point me to a resource or post an example?  I'm using the latest (ver 2.2.5).

I'm interested in making a custom "Cast" or custom "Select".  I can reflect the source code of existing extensions, and it is still non-obvious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common way to implement custom extensions in Rx (other than composing existing operations) is via `Observable.Create`. It is highly advisable to do it this way since `Create` takes care of a host of concerns that it is non-trivial to implement yourself.

However you do it, be sure to digest [the Rx Design Guidelines](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219) which explain the rules and conventions you should to follow - many of which `Observable.Create` takes care of for you.

Here is an example `Cast` implementation:

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<TResult> Cast<TSource, TResult>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source)
    {
        return Observable.Create<TResult>(o =>
            source.Subscribe(x => {
                TResult cast;
                try
                {
                    cast = (TResult)(object)x;                        
                }
                catch (InvalidCastException ex)
                {
                    o.OnError(ex);
                    return;
                }
                o.OnNext(cast);
            },
            o.OnError,
            o.OnCompleted));
    }
}
```

I put this as is, because the double cast requirement isn't obvious (actually `IEnumerable`'s `Cast` does the same thing, for the same reason). You can make this tweak to reduce the type arguments to one, given that the `object` cast is necessary:

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(
        this IObservable<object> source)
    {
        return Observable.Create<TResult>(o =>
            source.Subscribe(x => {
                TResult cast;
                try
                {
                    cast = (TResult)x;
                }
                catch (InvalidCastException ex)
                {
                    o.OnError(ex);
                    return;
                }
                o.OnNext(cast);
            },
            o.OnError,
            o.OnCompleted));
    }       
}
```

You can have a look at [IntroToRx](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#CreationOfObservables) for some more on `Observable.Create` too.

Comment: Just one correction: `o.OnNext` shouldn't be in the `try` block.

Comment: Yes, if a subscriber caused an `InvalidCastException`, it would be mishandled. Fixed, cheers.

Comment: Late to the game, but regarding your first implementation: Doesn't that leak resources because subscribing to the source is never unsubscribed even if no one actually uses the constructed cast observable anymore?

Comment: No, it's a subtle detail though - the creation logic is passing back the `IDisposable` to unsubscribe the source directly from the source itself.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is possible to create a new Rx operator by combining existing operators. For example the `Cast` operator could be implemented on top of the built-in `Select` operator like this:

```
public static IObservable<TResult> Cast<TSource, TResult>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source)
{
    return source.Select(x => (TResult)(object)x);
}
```

Comment: +1 This is worth stating explicitly - implicitly I assumed the OP was in a place where this approach wasn’t viable or more precise control was warranted. Using existing operators like this is a good idea when possible since it is much easier to avoid implementation gaffs.